# Apply forces to an object with python

Tags: python

I have a statue (really cool statue, I know)
[image]

This statue is not relly stable, if you apply a force to it in the wrong place, it falls.

My mission is to with python see where (on the "plane") you need to apply forces in order for the statue to fall. The "plane" of the statue is divided into smaller faces so the thing I need to do is to apply a force to each face?
How do I do that with python?

Sorry for any bad english